# Creating server-client tests for socket.io in python

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

Could anyone point a complete newbie to the place where I can learn about Python framework to test socket.io. I am pretty good at writing scripts for testing static API's but never worked with WebSocket before.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: checkout gevent http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/07/realtime-web-chat-with-socketio-and.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a large amount of examples using multiple popular frameworks in the example code for gevent-socketIO here https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python to talk with a socket.io server, you can use [socketIO-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client).

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

def on_bbb_response(*args):
    print 'on_bbb_response', args

with SocketIO('localhost', 8000) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('bbb', {'xxx': 'yyy'}, on_bbb_response)
    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is what i have tryed.

*server.py*

```py
import json
from aiohttp import web
import socketio

sio = socketio.AsyncServer()

# Creates a new Aiohttp Web Application
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('message')
async def print_message(sid, data):
    print("worked :")
    if data['type'] == "enter":
        print("----- "+data['username'] + " joined the room -----")
    elif data['type'] == "exit":
        print("----- "+data['username'] + " left the room -----")
    else:
        print(data['username']+" > "+data['message'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

*client.py*

```py
import time
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

sio.connect('http://localhost:8080')

username = input("Enter username : ") or "Unknown"

sio.emit("message", {'username':username,'message':'','type':'enter'})

while True:
    print("Enter message : ")
    msg = input()
    sio.emit("message", {'username':username,'message':msg,'type':'chat'})
    print("to quit press y")
    key = input()

    if key == 'y' or key == 'Y':
        sio.emit("message", {'username': username, 'message': "",'type':'exit'})
        time.sleep(1)
        sio.disconnect()
        break

sio.emit("message", {'username': username, 'message': msg})

print("you disconnected")
```